# Capturing a return value and output from bash function in a loop

Tags: linux, bash

Im a little confused, I have a function that returns a exit code value and is also returning output, from running two expect scripts (I produce an exit code from the first script, and output from the second, in the function).

I am trying to figure out how use this function in a loop.
I would like to loop the function until the exit code is zero, and then store the output value in a variable. 
Im a little stumped how to do this, I wonder if anyone can advise?
My goal is:

```
run_expect_scripts()
{
    expect expect_script1
    exit_value="$?"
    output=$(expect expect_script2)
    echo "$output"
    return "$exit_value"
}


until [ run_expect_scripts -eq 0 -o a_counter -eq 5 ]; do
    a_counter=$(expr a_counter + 1)
    sleep 2s
done
use output of run_expect_scripts
```

Please how can I do this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of dealing with this is to use a temp file:

```
#!/bin/bash

myfunc() {
   echo "output $RANDOM"
   return $((RANDOM % 5))
}

tmp=$(mktemp)
until myfunc > "$tmp" || (( count++ == 5)); do :; done
cat "$tmp"
```

Or if you don't want a temp file:

```
#!/bin/bash

myfunc() {
   echo "output $RANDOM"
   return $((RANDOM % 5))
}

ec=1
until [ $ec -eq 0 ] || (( count++ == 5)) 
do
  output=$(myfunc)
  ec=$?
done
echo "$output"
```